# How does std::string::erase remove characters from a string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

Consider the following code for example.

```
string str = "Alice ate apples"; 
str.erase(0, 2)
```

Does erase function actually allocate new memory and copy the "ice ate apples" or does erase function do an in-place copy?

Answer (score 7):

It is illegal for a `basic_string` implementation to have the iterator forms of `erase` throw exceptions. And even the index form of `erase` only throws when you provide an out-of-range index.

That's important because allocating memory is a potentially throwing operation. So if `erase` cannot throw, then it cannot *allocate* either. So it doesn't.

Therefore, the erasure must happen in-place.